# git pull error : /usr/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 86: /usr/bin/sed: Permission denied

Tags: git, github, sed

I am trying to do git pull and get below error,

```
/usr/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 86: /usr/bin/sed: Permission denied
```

I did successful git fetch and git merge. It is working however git pull does not work for any repository. Any help?

Thanks

Comment: To make it possible to help you, you need to specify more about the environment you are using git in. Who are you pulling from? Does it work with other repositories? Do you have anything interesting in your git config file?

Comment: I am using windows git. None od the repository works. Also I tried with different user and same problem. I tried on other machine and its works there. I compare config file and both has same info. Let me know what else you would like see.

Comment: The error you posted indicates a unix file system, so it is rather weird, that you are running git on windows. Did you install git through cygwin? Or which installer did you use? A `git --version` may be helpful.